# Array template syntax outside of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The syntax `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` can be used describe the (templated) type of a `unique_ptr` whose underlying raw pointer is pointing to an array of `T`s. I'm wondering what the syntax `T[]` means generally. Does it get used outside of smart pointers? Is it possible for e.g. `vector<T[]>` to ever be useful?

Answer (score 1):

It means "array of unknown bound of `T`". You might see such a type in function signatures:

```
void f(int arr[]);
```

In a declaration of an array defined elsewhere:

```
extern int arr[];
```

And obviously, as a type parameter to a template like `unique_ptr` (or, some time in the future, `shared_ptr` too). It's an incomplete type, so its usefulness can be rather limited.

`vector<T[]>` is unlikely to be useful. If you don't know how many elements are in the array, then how could you have a container of them?

Comment: It surprisingly possible to have an std::vector<int[]> but it seems impossible to use, and the copy semantics would not work.